# How can XML Injection be exploited , need example?

Tags: xml, penetration-test

So I found this explanation for a vulnerability on some cms :

> The XML parser at /WorkArea/Blogs/xmlrpc.aspx is vulnerable to XML
>   external entity attacks which can be used to Scan behind perimeter
>   firewalls or possibly include files from the local file system e.g.
>   ]> &test;

How can that issue be exploited . I have vulnerable cms on my home server. There isn't really much info on that. My goal is to learn something new. THanka

Comment: I guess this sums it up perfectly: https://www.owasp.org/images/5/5d/XML_Exteral_Entity_Attack.pdf#page=30

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The XML syntax allows for automatic inclusion of other files, which can be on the same system, or even elsewhere (through a URL). See for instance [this documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipgentity/index.html). The attack would be conceptually a case where the attacker can add an "external entity reference" in a piece of XML which will be interpreted as XML by a machine (e.g. a Web server), with the rights of that server; the attacker can then make the machine read a local file of his choosing (a file local *to the server*) and include it in the interpreted XML. If the interpreted XML is then sent back to the attacker, then the attacker gains a read access to the server local files.

We could imagine that in a CMS system, where the attacker can insert messages with a XML syntax. If the CMS allows *arbitrary* XML from the attacker, then the attacker can use external entities to read and display files like `/etc/passwd` (or even `/etc/shadow` if the CMS runs as `root`).

Comment: Brilliant explanation; even I understood. +1